# Use ~/.ssh/config hosts in docker context

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm trying to find a way to use hosts defined in my user's `~/.ssh/config` file to define a docker context.

My `~/.ssh/config` file contains:

```
Host my-server
  HostName 10.10.10.10
  User remoteuser
  IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-mykey.pub
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I'd like to create a docker context as follow:

```
docker context create \
       --docker host=ssh://my-server \
       --description="remoteuser on 10.10.10.10" \
       my-server
```

Issuing the `docker --context my-server ps` command throws an error stating:

> ... please make sure the URL is valid ... Could not resolve hostname my-server: Name or service not known

For what I could figure out, the `docker` command uses the `sudo` mechanism to elevate its privileges. Thus I guess it searches `/root/.ssh/config`, since `ssh` doesn't use the `$HOME` variable.

I tried to symlink the user's config as the root one:

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/.ssh/config /root/.ssh/config
```

But this throws another error:

> ... please make sure the URL is valid ... Bad owner or permissions on /home/user/.ssh/config

The same happens when creating the `/root/.ssh/config` file simply containing:

```
Include /home/*/.ssh/config
```

Does someone have an idea on how to have my user's `.ssh/config` file parsed by ssh when issued via `sudo` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed your (probably correct) theory that docker is running as root, by just directly copying your user's `~/.ssh/config` contents into `/root/.ssh/config`?  If that doesn't work, you're back to square one...

Otherwise, either the symlink or the Include ought to work just fine (a symlink inherits the permissions of the file it is pointing at).

Another possibility is that your permissions actually are bad -- don't forget you have to change the permissions on both `~/.ssh`  AND `~/.ssh/config`.

```
chmod 700 /home/user/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/config
```

And maybe even:

```
chmod 700 /root/.ssh
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/config
```

Comment: I confirm docker is running as root on the system. Using a symlink in /root/.ssh/ and setting the most permissive rights (777) on the /home/user/.ssh/ directory and (755) on the config file didn't work. The message is always: Bad owner or permissions on /root/.ssh/config
Using the "Include" statement in /root/.ssh/config always gives: Bad owner or permissions on /home/user/.ssh/config
Duplicating the content of the user config file into /root/.ssh/config works as expected, but this forces me to always keep the 2 files synchronized, which is exactly what I was trying to avoid, too bad!

Comment: Actually, I think setting the most permissive rights for the .ssh directory and config file is guaranteed NOT to work -- those files will only be used if the permissions are not too loose.   If you're still working on this problem, you might want to try setting the permissions to 700 and 600 respectively...